# Getting the "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" error for a pay() function

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing

I'm getting the following error during the testing in Truffle:

> ```
>  Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
> ```

It simply says "revert" without the contingency message, which tells me that it's not coming from any of the "require" functions I've defined.  I've also tried running the test with everything else commented out, except for the "pay()" function, including all the other test, but still didn't work.

**testing**

```js
it("can pay the payout from the pending credit to the proper beneficiary", async () => {
    // ARRANGE
    let beneficiary = accounts[2];
    let flightAddress = accounts[4];
    let initialBalance;
    let postBalance;
    let eventEmitted = false;
    // ACT
    try {
      initialBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(beneficiary);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
    await config.flightSuretyData.buy(beneficiary, 100, flightAddress);
    await config.flightSuretyData.creditInsurees(beneficiary);
    await config.flightSuretyData.pay({ from: beneficiary }); // right here!
    await config.flightSuretyData.contract.events.InsurancePayoutPaid(
      function () {
        eventEmitted = true;
      }
    );
    try {
      postBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(beneficiary);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    }
    assert.equal(
      postBalance - initialBalance,
      result,
      "The insurance payout failed"
    );
    assert.isTrue(eventEmitted, "The event InsurancePayoutPaid is not emitted");
  });
```

**contract**

```
    function pay() external payable requireIsOperational {
        require(msg.sender != address(0), "Not a valid address");
        require(
            insurance[msg.sender].isValue == true,
            "The caller is not insured"
        );
        require(
            pendingCredit[msg.sender] != 0,
            "The pending credit amount is 0"
        );
        uint256 payout = pendingCredit[msg.sender];
        pendingCredit[msg.sender] = 0;
        msg.sender.transfer(payout);
        // address(uint160(msg.sender)).transfer(payout);
        emit InsurancePayoutPaid(msg.sender, payout);
    }
```

I thought maybe it had to do with the gas limit so I tried :

`await config.flightSuretyData.pay({ from: beneficiary, gasPrice: 0 });`

**or**

`await config.flightSuretyData.pay({ from: beneficiary, gas: 0 });`

But none worked.

I've tried :

`web3.utils.fromWei(postBalance) - web3.utils.fromWei(initialBalance)` for the assertion

**or**

`"web3.utils.fromWei(100)"` for the argument for the `buy()` function, but that wasn't it either.

Finally, I've deleted the build, `truffle migrate --reset` and then tried testing again, but still the same result.

Comment: What is `requireIsOperational`?

Comment: Also, you probably want to add `require(address(this).balance >= payout, "insufficient amount of ether in the contract");` before `msg.sender.transfer(payout);`.